# Поиск "битых" ссылок на внешние файлы Excel

Tags: excel, vba, макросы, макрос

**I. Описание проблемы**

Очень часто в сложных (многолистовых) файлах Excel возникает такая проблема: когда хочешь "разорвать" ссылки на внешние файлы (заменить их значениями), то некоторые ссылки на старинские файлы не убиваются и найти эти старинские файлы не представляется возможным.
Я задался вопросом обнаружить ячейки или любые объекты книги, которые ссылаются на внешние файлы.
Ниже представлен код, который репортит на отдельный лист адреса ячеек, которые ссылаются на внешние файлы:

```
Sub ListLinks()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim xLinkArr() As String
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xSheet In Worksheets
        Set xRg = xSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If xRg Is Nothing Then GoTo LblNext
        For Each xCell In xRg
            If InStr(1, xCell.Formula, "[") > 0 Then
                xCount = xCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve xLinkArr(1 To 2, 1 To xCount)
                xLinkArr(1, xCount) = xCell.Address(, , , True)
                xLinkArr(2, xCount) = "'" & xCell.Formula
           End If
        Next
LblNext:
    Next
    If xCount > 0 Then
        Sheets.Add(Sheets(1)).Name = "Link Sheet"
        Range("A1").Resize(, 2).Value = Array("Location", "Reference")
        Range("A2").Resize(UBound(xLinkArr, 2), UBound(xLinkArr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(xLinkArr)
        Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    Else
        MsgBox "No links were found within the active workbook."
    End If
End Sub
```

Однако прогнав, данный код по файлу, который содержит битую ссылку я не смог идентифицировать ячейку, которая ссылается на несуществующий файл.

Отсюда делаю вывод, что кроме ячеек ссылаться могут и другие объекты Excel.

**II. Постановка задачи**

Помогите пожалуйста доработать код, которые идентифицирует не только ячейки (и в отдельном листе прописывает их путь), но и все другие объекты, которые могут ссылаться на внешние файлы?

**III. Решение №1 (с помощью стандартного ф-ла Excel)**

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

1. Давим F5
2. Получаем скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Получаем скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вообще-то у Range есть свойство HasFormula - так что мутить всякое `InStr(1, xCell.Formula, "[") > 0` не есть правильно.

Comment: Плюс [Поиск связей (внешних ссылок) в книге](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1)

Comment: 2Акина: 1. Поиск связей, который Вы предложили стандартными средствами Excel реализован макросом, но более удобно так как репортится в отдельный массив данных, который легче анализировать, чем из формы "Поиск связей..." (Вы глазками что ли смотреть будете тысячи строк?); 2. Рекомендации по оптимизации кода на мой взгляд нужно давать после того как решена поставленная задача (иначе ранняя дискуссия не будет способствовать решению поставленной задачи); 3. Призываю Вас поддерживать миссию данного ресурса - помогать, а не ставить палки в колёса!

Comment: 1) Этот макрос переводится на VBA практически влоб - он же тупо выполняет Range.Find, и потом просто красиво отображает результат. Вам же из статьи надо было взять только информацию о том, что именно и в чём именно искать. 2) Это не означает, что надо выполнять элементарные операции через опу - готовое решение, как правило, объёмно, и разбираться, можно ли оптимизировать конструкцию, и как, будет гораздо труднее. Намного разумнее сразу использовать оптимальные конструкции. 3) Что именно показалось Вам "палкой в колесе"? Вроде ни запретов, ни ложных сведений в моих комментариях нет...

Comment: 1. Если вывыливается более 1000 строк, то как удобнее искать: глазками или в "красивом" отображённом результате, где легче найти?; 2. Если Вы предлагаете оптимизацию кода, то будьте добры тогда предоставить оптимизированный код на Ваш взгляд (это всегда субъективно и уверен на Вашу "оптимизацию" найдётся ещё более оптимизированный код. То есть путём нескольких итераций будет достигнут оптимизированный код. Но для этого Вам необходимо также приложить усилия чтобы не полениться и написать этот код. А так получаются только советы... 3. См. п.п.2. Резюме: Вы хотите только давать советы...

Comment: Не забывайте, что Ваши советы могут быть однозначно понятны профессионалам. Но скидываете со счетов новичков, которым Ваши советы могут быть не понятны. И тут поможет предоставление Вами кода (ну или хотя бы строки кода, которую Вы хотели бы соптимизировать/изменить/переписать - нужное подчеркнуть). Вот под этим я и имел в виду "палки". Основная цель: достижение результатов. И это достижение результатов для профессионалов может быть одно, а для новичков другое (может быть более длинное и трудоёмкое). Для этого и просят помощи...

Comment: Возвращаясь к задаче: на данный момент она была решена стандартным (пользовательским интерфейсом с помощью стандартного ф-ла) без применения ф-ла макросов. Однако представляет интерес реализация решения посредством макроса. Но видимо здесь без помощи профессионалов мне будет сложно продвинуться с макросом далее... Это грустно...

Comment: 1) Да не вопрос. Как я сказал - реализуйте такой же поиск, как делает встроенный макро, но в своей VBA-программе, и выводите так, как считаете более обозримым. 2) Так и будут только советы. Код будете писать исключительно Вы. Впрочем, никто не запрещает советами не пользоваться. 3) Сейчас скажу обидное. Вы, похоже относитесь к той категории участников, которые, получив хоть какой ответ, садятся ровно и ждут, когда всё сделают за них. *Ваши советы могут быть однозначно понятны профессионалам* Ну так становитесь им - Вы же за этим сюда пришли? Учитесь понимать и применять советы.